# Can a VariableDeclarator exist without being a member of a VariableDeclaration in standard C# analysis?

Tags: c#, roslyn

The VariableDeclarator is usually a child of VariableDeclaration. Is this always the case during standard CSharp analysis?

Comment: You might have better luck with these sorts of questions on the C# discord (there's a Roslyn channel): https://aka.ms/discord-csharp-roslyn or gitter: https://gitter.im/dotnet/roslyn

Comment: @canton7 thanks canton7 , deep in the weeds here with csharp analysis

Comment: If you learned the answer I encourage you to post it here anyway since having an answer that can show up in a web search is bound to be useful for posterity :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VariableDeclarators are always part of a VariableDeclaration. The syntax rules specification is [declared here](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/main/src/Compilers/CSharp/Portable/Generated/CSharp.Generated.g4).